# MySQL user has "usage" privileges but RW works

Tags: mysql, permissions, database, grafana

I have migrated Grafana from SQLite database to MySQL (in fact, MariaDB 10.3.22), so database is now located on a different machine. It is obvious that the software needs a database account now, so I created a separate one:

```
MariaDB [(grafana)]> create user 'grafana'@'%' identified by 'XX';
```

Then, I adjusted Grafana configuration file to use the newly created account. And everything worked. The thing is that I cannot understand how it works when it comes to privileges (the goal is to apply least privileges possible). I didn't assign any privileges to the new user. Current ones:

```
MariaDB [(grafana)]> show grants for grafana;
| Grants for grafana@% |
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'grafana'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'XX' |
```

MySQL documentation says, that "usage" privilege (assigned on creation time) is a synonym for "no privilege". In another words, I should expect that Grafana wouldn't work at all. But it works like a charm.

How is that possible that reads and writes are possible? Neither could I find any reasonable explanation on this topic nor similar threads.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you forgot to restart grafana after the configuration change?
If not, it's still using SQLite, which would explain why it's still working.

Comment: Nope, it is definitely not using SQLite. Grafana's read/write abilities were verified by live queries to MySQL instance, not only in GUI.

Comment: can you post the output of  "show databases" when you're connected as the grafana user on mariadb

Comment: 'show databases;' while being connected as a 'grafana' user shows two databases: grafana, information schema.

Comment: I was able to sort of reproduce the problem. Just to check if i'm on the right track, would you mind running "select Db,User from mysql.db where Db='grafana';"

When the user column is empty, i am able to use the grafana database as the grafana user, even though the grafana user has only usage privileges like in your case.

Comment: It seems I've found the issue. When I ran the above command, it showed 3 rows, all of them with a different value in 'host' column – IPs of Grafana server, database and localhost. The first one (with IP of Grafana server) had full privileges, others had only select_priv set as 'Y'.
i deleted all of the rows with user='grafana', recreated the database from .sql file (I guess that doesn't matter here) and now it's taking user privileges into account.
So I assume that was the reason – more specific host value of a user took precedence over just %. If I'm right, thank you for your help.